# Could not create type 'JSONWebAPI.Handler1'. on live server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, handler

Am sure this has been answered before, but am struggling to find the exact solution for my scenario,

Below is the scenario,

Am trying to create a webservice to call the sql server from android device, so am seeking help from generic hanlder in asp.net.

**Handler1.ashx:**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind = "Handler1.ashx.cs"  Class="JSONWebAPI.Handler1" %>
```

**Handler1.ashx.cs:**

```
using JsonServices;
using JsonServices.Web;

namespace JSONWebAPI
{
   public class Handler1 : JsonHandler
   {
      public Handler1()
      {
        // Code
      }

    }
}
```

**The reason for asking question is,**

That it works fine in localhost, but it's not at all working in Live Website. I have deployed this webservie in one of the live website named as "xxyy.com". I transferred all the files inside of JSONWebAPI folder to the website. So am calling the handler1.ashx with the help of below url,

```
http://www.xxyy.com/JSONWebAPI/Handler1.ashx.
```

But repeatedly am getting the error as ,

```
 Could not create type 'JSONWebAPI.Handler1'.
```

**What i tried is,**

I have tried all the possible answers from the stack overflow relating to my question. Few are,

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="JSONWebAPI.Handler1" %>
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind = "Handler1.ashx.cs"  Class="Handler1" %>
```

But nothing is working in my case.

Hope you understand my difficulties. Any help would be more thankful.

Answer (score 0):

install iis
copy you project to root folder (wwwroot)
open iis manager right click on your project and click on make web application